# How to load a protocol buffer binary file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, protocol-buffers

I have generated a binary file containing some data using protobuf in Python, and I need to load the binary file now in Javascript and read its content. I tried to use `FileReader()` but I wasn't able to succeed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `protobufjs`.

Here's an example in JavaScript:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const protobuf = require('protobufjs');

// Load the binary data
const binaryData = fs.readFileSync('your-protocol-buffer-file.bin');

// Load the root of the protocol buffer definition
const root = protobuf.Root.fromJSON(yourProtoJSON);

// Look up the desired message type
const MyMessageType = root.lookupType('MyMessageType');

// Decode the binary data using the message type
const message = MyMessageType.decode(binaryData);

// The message object is a JavaScript object that represents the data in the binary file
console.log(message);
```

You will need to have the Protocol Buffer definition (.proto file) that was used to generate the binary file in order to use `protobufjs` to decode the data.

For more information on protobufjs, you can visit https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js.